# Spotlight not illuminating. Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, lighting

Little trouble here.
i've got spotlight emitting light on the cube (in rendered view), but the cube does not get illuminated.
[image]

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it does, but it's really weak: try  setting background to grey, and disable sun rendering, to see it better, then enhance spot strength to 10.000:

here it is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Did not try to raise strenght that high :D

Comment: That high value is needed, imho because your cube is black. A light grey cube need a less strong spot light, apparently. IRL black color means "absorbs most visile light", maybe Cycles is reflecting that...